# Python 3.5.1 IDLE keeps crashing on Mac OSX 10.11.4

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, python-idle

I'm running IDLE with python 3.5.1 by python.org, but it keeps crashing.
The shell starts with 
"WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.
Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information."
As recommended on that site I installed ActiveTcl 8.5.18.0, but that doesn't seem to have helped.
This message is relatively new, maybe since the OSX update to 10.11.4.

Any suggestions what might cause these crashes? 
Thanks

@OSX 10.11.4 MacBook Air 13" 2013, i7, 8GB Ram

Update:

I called Idle via Terminal with `python3 -m idlelib` and then About Idle. It says Python and IDLE Version 3.5.1 an Tk Version 8.5.9.
I also noticed that when I click on README in the IDLE section, it prints an error on the terminal:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File  "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/idlelib/aboutDialog.py", line 127, in ShowIDLEAbout
self.display_file_text('About - Readme', 'README.txt')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/idlelib/aboutDialog.py", line 139, in display_file_text
textView.view_file(self, title, fn, encoding)           File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/idlelib/textView.py", line 74, in view_file
contents = file.read()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 72: invalid start byte
```

Comment: maybe that warning about Tcl is important?...

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my mac. Can you provide hardware information about your computer?

Comment: just added info above

Comment: Try deleting your current Python folder and re-install Python from python.org.

Comment: try running idle from the terminal with the command `python -m idlelib` then the output for idle will be shown on the terminal, if there are errors raised in IDLE's internals you can see them and post them here.

Comment: if you named your file something that conflicts with the standard library like `code.py` it would cause a lot of problems with the inner mechanics of IDLE.

Comment: If you still see the warning, then I presume that you are still using the unstable Apple version of tcl/tk.  When IDLE starts, look at Help -> About IDLE to check the Tk version.

Comment: thanks, I posted an update

Comment: Your update says you are using 8.5.9.  Carefully read `python.org/download/mac/tcltk` and upgrade to 8.5.18.  Before Python 3.7.0 is released, the python.org mac binary will be changed to use tcl/tk 8.6.x, with many bug fixes for macOS.

Answer (score 0):

For me, 90% of IDLE crashes were caused by typing a left-parenthesis — very annoying. 
In IDLE, you can fix it by:

```
Options Menu > Configure Extensions > CallTips > set to FALSE
```

Then restart.